# How to print words found in text that are from dictionary as a list?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 documents: 
The first one is a .txt document which is a dictionary made like this:

```
Box OB
Table OB
Tiger AN
Lion AN
```

The second document is a .txt file with a long text in in. Like this one.

There in a box. A lion and a tiger are in that box.

I want to list how many times the words that are in my dictionary occur in my text.

Kind of like this:

```
Box: 2 
Lion: 1 
Tiger: 1
```

This is what I did:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import codecs


file = codecs.open("MYtext.txt",'r','utf-8')
text = file.readlines()
line_list = []

for line in text:
    line.rstrip('\n')
    line_list.append(line)

d = {}
import nltk 
with open("MYdict.txt",) as mydict:
    for line in mydict:
        (key, val) = line.split()
        dictionary = dict(line.strip().split(None, 1) for line in mydict)

line_counter = 0
for line in line_list:
    line_counter = line_counter + 1

for word in line.split():
    if word in line_list in dictionary.keys():
        line_list = dictionary[word]
        line_list.append(line_counter)
        dictionary[word] = line_list
    else:
        line_list = []
        line_list.append(line_counter)
        dictionary[word] = line_list
for key in sorted(dictionary.keys()):
    print key, len(dictionary[key])
```

I am getting this error

```
    $ /var/folders/3h/w3_12zfs7hs6zcrlnpk8gdg40000gn/T/Cleanup\ At\ Startup/test\ 44-405955317.432.py.command ; exit;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/folders/3h/w3_12zfs7hs6zcrlnpk8gdg40000gn/T/Cleanup At Startup/test 44-405955317.367.py", line 33, in <module>
    for key in sorted(dictionary.keys()):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
logout

[Process completed]
```

Can you please help. I'm new to this. I'm a linguist, not a programmer.

Comment: Please give us the complete stack trace.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find words using a dictionary in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918541/how-to-find-words-using-a-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong about your code that are initially not related to the error you're getting.

You should group your `import`s at the top of the file. The `import nltk` line should not be in the middle of your code

You shold process the dictionary first. About that, you have an outer loop (`for line in mydict`) and then, inside, there's another loop (actually a list comprehension). Not good. You can simply use:

```
with open("MYdict.txt",) as mydict:
    dictionary = dict(line.strip().split(None, 1) for line in mydict)
```

However it would be good to save the strings in lowercase:

```
with open("MYdict.txt",) as mydict:
    dictionary = {x[0].lower(): x[1] for x in [line.strip().split(None, 1) for line in mydict]}
```

In order to read, strip and store the lines from the text, you can use the `splitlines` method of the strings, like this:

```
with codecs.open("MYtext.txt",'r','utf-8') as mytext:
    line_list = mytext.read().splitlines()
```

However it's better to process the file line by line, instead of saving all the lines.

There's no need to use a `for` loop to count the lines. Just use `len(line_list)`.

I don't quite get what you did in the last part of the code. You seem to mess with some previous variables (like `line` from the previous loop) and overwrite the `line_list` variable.

This is one way of doing it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import codecs

with open("MYdict.txt",) as mydict:
    dictionary = {x[0].lower(): x[1] for x in [line.strip().split(None, 1) for line in mydict]}

word_count = {}

with codecs.open("MYtext.txt",'r','utf-8') as mytext:
    for line in mytext:
        for word in line.strip().split():
            word = word.rstrip('.,')
            if word in dictionary.keys():
                word_count[word] = word_count.get(word, 0) + 1

for key in sorted(word_count, key=word_count.get, reverse=True):
    print "%s : %i" % (key, word_count[key])
```

You can of course merge the two for loops in one, just using `for word in (line.strip().split() for line in mytext)`

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting probably has to do with the encoding of `"MYdict.txt"`. I think if you would use the `codecs.open` method with the `'utf-8'` flag just like you did for the other file you can fix this.

If I understand properly what you like to do, I think I would tackle it like so:

```
import codecs

with codecs.open('MYdict.txt',  'r', 'utf-8') as f:
    wordslist = [line.split()[0].lower() for line in f]

with codecs.open('MYtext.txt',  'r', 'utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read().lower()

counts = {}
for word in wordslist:
    counts[word] = text.count(word)


# alternatively instead of the last 3 lines
# you can use a "dictionary comprehension"
counts = {word: text.count(word) for word in wordslist}
```

For pretty printing the output you could use:

```
import pprint

pprint.pprint(counts)
```